# Vector Resizing in C++ (Scaling Down )

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I read from TopCoder STL Tutorials and some other standard tutorials which says, if i `resize()` a vector to a lower value than the original value, the last 'difference' number of elements would be deleted. But,

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include<vector>
     using namespace std;
     int main() {
     vector<int> v(20); 
     for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
     v[i] = i; 
      } 
     v.resize(10); 
     for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
     cout<<v[i]<<" ";
     return 0;
     }
```

returns the same elements i have initialized till V[20]. The Elements from V[10] to V[19] should be initialized to zero or a garbage value right? Or if i am understanding it wrong, could someone throw some light?

Comment: Accessing elements from `10` to `19` is undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: Accessing a vector out of range is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Don't do it.

Comment: So what is the need for down scale  resize() . Does that make no sense, since no elements get deleted ? What is the use of that?

Comment: Try that with `vec.at(i)`.

Comment: @SubramanianS the elements do get deleted. trying to reason about the behavior of a program which has UB is nonsensical and pointless.

Comment: @SubramanianS They get deleted. But accessing deleted elements can get any result, including the old values. This tutorial is bad, search a better one.

Comment: *"Does that make no sense, since no elements get deleted? What is the use of that?"* - if you check `.size()`, iterate from `.begin()` to `.end()` or `for (auto x : v)` etc. you'll see the elements were erased; `.at(10)` or higher will start throwing, and if you `.push_back` more elements they'll be at indices `[10]` onwards: the `resize()` would have called destructors for more complicated objects, potentially releasing resources such as dynamically allocated memory or flushing and closing streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resize()` will resize the vector and make the last elements invalid, but not as you assume. You can clearly see by checking how many elements the vector has in it that there are 10. However, this does *not* mean that the allocated memory would be thrown away or that the removed elements would be invalid in some sense, especially them being integers.

THe vector *may* reallocate memory, if it so chooses. Then the last elements would be impossible to access.

Basically you are invoking undefined behaviour by accessing a vector over its limits. Anything can happen. In this case the implementation chose not to reallocate the memory (which is smart, since the difference is so small), so you can point to elements out of bounds.

If the elements were objects, they would've been deleted and you would have even more undefined behaviour by dereferencing a deleted object.

Answer (score 2):

This is technically undefined behavior, as others have pointed out.

What is going on is that resizing a vector to a lower size does not guarantee that memory will be deallocated and reallocated in a smaller chunk (the so called "shrink-to-fit" operation). This is for performance reasons.

So you likely won't get an access violation if you try to access elements that were removed from the vector, but those objects *are* destroyed, and if you had removed objects with a non-trivial destructor rather than integers, that destructor would have been executed for each erased object.

The reason why you do not see nulled-out values is - again - performance: those `int` objects have been destroyed, so they are not supposed to be accessed anyway. Why bother losing time to reset the region of memory they occupied with some default (or even garbage) content?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `resize` on a `std::vector` changes the vector's size, default-inserting (or copy-inserting) or deleting additional or excess elements. [[reference]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).
In your case, deleting excess elements is what matters.

What does that mean for your example?

It means that the `int` objects are formally destroyed, but the destructor does nothing. The bit pattern stored in memory and the reserve size of the `vector` are not changed (`resize` doesn't specify that, although it's not strictly forbidden to the implementation to do it anyway), therefore accessing the deleted elements seems to "work", no segmentation fault or such occurs, and the values are seemingly still present.
An integer that has been deleted is -- incidentially -- still valid unless it's eventually overwritten, since it's just a bit pattern in a memory cell. It's nowhere near well-defined as far as the language goes, however (nor is it wise to do it).

The fact that this "works" is pure coincidence and nothing you can rely on. With many non-trivial types, deleting an object will render it invalid. Also, accessing a vector's elements out of range, or accessing an object after the end of its lifetime is strictly undefined behavior. Which, again, means no more and no less than although it "works", it only works by coincidence in your case (you might indeed trigger a range check in a debug build, and an optimizing compiler that detects your invocation of UB might optimize your program in a non-obvious way).

Answer (score 0):

the memory is not reinitialized so if the memory is not reallocate you can access it with the random iterator but if you do a yourVector.size() the returned value should be different

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the VC12 implementation of resize():

```
if (_Newsize < size())
    _Pop_back_n(size() - _Newsize);
else if (size() < _Newsize)
    {   // pad as needed
    ...
    }
```

There are 2 branches, 1 if the resize is less than the current size, and one if it is greater. For resizing a vector to smaller than it currently is, `_Pop_back_n()` is used which is defined as:

```
pointer _Ptr = this->_Mylast - _Count;
_Destroy(_Ptr, this->_Mylast);
this->_Mylast = _Ptr;
```

So this simply moves the pointer down by the number of elements to be removed and deallocates the excess memory from the vector. It does no cleaning up of the deallocated memory, so the values will still be the same until they are overwritten.